# How can I make analog of list comprehension, which uses less RAM?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

There's a function that creates a list, which contains all combinations of elements in 12 another lists

```
def make_list(self):
    results = ['{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5,x6,x7,x8,x9,x10,x11,x12)
               for x1 in self.list1
                    for x2 in self.list2
                        for x3 in self.list3
                            for x4 in self.list4
                                for x5 in self.list5
                                    for x6 in self.list6
                                        for x7 in self.list7
                                            for x8 in self.list8
                                                for x9 in self.list9
                                                    for x10 in self.list10
                                                        for x11 in self.list11
                                                            for x12 in self.list12]
```

But it using too many RAM, as expected.
Is there any solution that can use less memory?
I tried to use `map()`, but I don't quite understand what function it could be.

Or the best solution is to rewrite this on C++ or Go?

Comment: What do you do with this results list?

Comment: @DanD. Just write it to the field in PyQt5 app.

Comment: If you need the result as a list, it will always use the same RAM, no matter how you create it. But if you only need to iterate the list once, you can use a generator expression instead. Simply replace the outer `[...]` for `(...)`.

Comment: I'm kind of doubtful that this is what you really want, though. This will create the formatted string for each _combination_ of elements from all those 12 lists.

Comment: You have 12 nested loops so you are creating about `n**12` where `n` is the average number of elements of one of those lists... that grows quickly. If `n` is 2 the list willl be 4096, if it is 3 it's already in the half-million elements range and if it is 4 it goes to ~17 millions. I don't think that generating 17 million elements to display in PyQt is a good idea. You generally define a model that lazily loads only the values displayed.

Comment: Maybe you should tell us what you really want to do. As others pointed out, you're creating every combination possible of the 12 lists (disregarding order) using this code and I don't think that's what you need. Did you want to concatenate the 12 lists? Do you want to have a list containing the 12 lists? Do you really want every combination of the 12 lists?

Comment: @tobias_k Yes, i need to display all combinations of elements of all those 12 lists. Sorry if i poorly explaiend this in question.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle Yes, i need to display all combinations of elements of all those 12 lists. Sorry if i poorly explaiend this in question

Comment: In this case - don't create all at once. As Giacomo already said, use lazy evaluation.

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta i need to display all of those values.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle so it sounds like `def func(el, lst):
    # print(lst)
    for line1 in lst:
        el += " " + line1
    return el
 
lists = {'s' : ["ss", "ff", "dd"]
's1' : ["aa", "gg", "hh"]
's2' : ["ww", "kk", "ll"]}
import itertools
for values in lists.values():
    map(func, s, itertools.repeat(values))`

Comment: How many values are there in a list?

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle The number of values is dynamic. But on average, let's say, 40 items in each list.

Comment: You could also provide a button called next or so. Then, you show the first `x` combinations (with `x` not being too big, let's say `x <= 100`) and then you just load the first `x` combinations, when clicking on `Next` you create the next `x` combinations etc. This way you can lazily load and still display everything. Amazon does the same :)

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle I guess my stack is clogged because of the loop. In the case of a conditional output of 17 million values, it will be very inconvenient to press the button for every 100. If i'll do this without a button, for example with timeouts, will it free my RAM?

Comment: "on average, let's say 40 items in each list". So, you want to display _all_ those ~16,777,216,000,000,000,000 elements?

Comment: Or do you want to display the first elements from all the lists, then all the second element, all the thirds, etc.?

Comment: @tobias_k now it works righ like i want. I can check this by using a few elements in every list.

Comment: Do you realize that your screen probably has less than 4 million *pixels*? One of those strings will probably need at least ~1K pixel to be readable so you can, *at best*, display 4000 values.  Which means you need 4250 "screenfulls" to display all 17M values. If you create a paginated view it will have at least 4250 pages. Do you see why what you are doing does not really make sense? Looking at one page every 10 seconds (i.e they read 4k strings in 10 seconds! Superman level speed) will take 11 hours to scroll all of them. Change your approach...

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta I dont need humans to read all of them :D. I need to show them just for user can copy all of them and then paste to another app :D

Comment: @AgeofCreationsJust save them to a file then.

Comment: There is still a problem with the loop. It takes memory, not output.

Comment: like Giacomo said, save it in a file. Then you can use lazy evaluation (using loops and `yield` perhaps) to save memory. nobody wants to scroll some windows for billions of lines just to copy data to another app. Files are much easier to exchange.

Comment: @TobiasBrösamle if u make answer like that i'd like to mark this a salvation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem isn't *how* you generate the list, but the fact that you want an enormous list in the first place. Instead, generate the tuples lazily with a generator. (You'll never have time to actually iterate over the entire sequence, but it's theoretically possible.)

The easiest way to do this is with `itertools.product`.

```
import itertools

tuples = itertools.product(self.list1, self.list2, ..., self.list12)

# This will run virtually forever, but never use more memory than is needed for
# a single tuple
for t in tuples:
   print('{} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {} {}'.format(*t))
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you’re trying to keep in memory all of the possible combinations (because you building a string and return in one piece.) In your case of [cartesean product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) you will have to produce (for 12 lists and approximately 40 items) about 40¹² combinations. Even if each element of your list takes only one byte you will need about [17 Exabytes](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=40%5E12+bytes) and in a textual form, it takes a few times more.

But you can produce all these combinations without insane memory demands. You can use sliding indices to print all possibilities.

Just for an educational purpose, I’ll give an example solution on how to produce all these combinations without consuming tredecillions of the RAM memory which works for variable lists number:

```py
from random import randint

# It easier to read code which words rather than with numbers
# These are more meaningful names for positions in indices list

INDEX = 0  # Index in the actual list we are taking for combination
LENGTH = 1  # Calculated length of the actual list
LIST = 2  # Reference to the actual list

AVERAGE_SIZE = 4
DEVIATION = 1


class Demo(object):
    list1 = list(randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(0, AVERAGE_SIZE + randint(-DEVIATION, +DEVIATION)))
    list2 = list(randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(0, AVERAGE_SIZE + randint(-DEVIATION, +DEVIATION)))
    list3 = list(randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(0, AVERAGE_SIZE + randint(-DEVIATION, +DEVIATION)))
    list4 = list(randint(-100, 100) for _ in range(0, AVERAGE_SIZE + randint(-DEVIATION, +DEVIATION)))

    def combinations(self):
        """Generator of all possible combinations. Yields one combination as comma separated string at a time"""
        indices = [
            # Actual list index start, length of the actual list, reference to that list
            [0, len(self.list1) - 1, self.list1],
            [0, len(self.list2) - 1, self.list2],
            [0, len(self.list3) - 1, self.list3],
            [0, len(self.list4) - 1, self.list4],
        ]

        total_positions = len(indices)

        # Calculate number of the the all possible combinations
        rounds = None
        for item in indices:
            if rounds is None:
                rounds = item[LENGTH] + 1
            else:
                rounds *= (item[LENGTH] + 1)

        current_round = 0  # Combination index

        while current_round < rounds:
            combination = list()
            carry_position = 0
            for current_position in range(0, total_positions):
                # Take a triple of index, length and list at current position (for easier readability)
                current_item = indices[current_position]

                # Pick current combination
                combination.append(current_item[LIST][current_item[INDEX]])

                # If current position under carry
                if current_position <= carry_position:
                    # Advance actual index unless it reached end of its list
                    if indices[current_position][INDEX] < indices[current_position][LENGTH]:
                        indices[current_position][INDEX] = indices[current_position][INDEX] + 1
                        carry_position = 0
                    else:  # If index of current list at the end
                        indices[current_position][INDEX] = 0  # Move actual list index to the start
                        carry_position = current_position + 1  # Remember that next poison have carry
                # Repeat for each position

            # Yield collected combination
            yield ','.join(str(x) for x in combination)

            current_round += 1

        raise StopIteration

    def print_combinations(self):
        """Prints all of the combinations"""
        for combination in self.combinations():
            print(combination)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Demo().print_combinations()
```

This solution is generic and you can easily add more lists but *be aware* with `AVERAGE_SIZE` of 40 and 12 lists even if you dump results into a file you will need more than one billion of the 1 terabyte hard disks for the storage.